# Abrir e iniciar sesión en SAP desde una macro de Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sap

Este código me abre desde una macro de Excel el SAP, y me abre una ventana donde escribo el usuario y contraseña de mi servidor/conexión en SAP, pero al dar aceptar éste no funciona.

La macro no corre bien en el SAP a la hora de seleccionar en la lista de conexiones la mía.

```vb
Dim sapConn As Object

Set objshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objapp = objshell.Exec("C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplgpad.exe")
Set sapConn = CreateObject("SAP.Functions") 'Create ActiveX object

sapConn.Connection.ApplicationServer = "C:\Program Files\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe"
sapConn.Connection.client = "010" ' only read access
sapConn.Connection.user = Environ("USER")
sapConn.Connection.Password = "PASSWORD"
sapConn.Connection.System = "SYSTEM"
sapConn.Connection.Language = "ES"
If sapConn.Connection.logon(0, False) <> True Then 'Try Logon
    MsgBox "Cannot Log on to SAP"
    getSAPProjectHours = False
Else

 sapConn.Connection.Logoff
End If
Set sapConn = Nothing
```

Comment: Pudiste hacer el login?.... Estoy haciendo unos scrpt, y estoy buscando como hacer que desde la macro, abra el SAP y valide el login,,, bueno,,, luego de esta validacion, que corra mi script. Me quedo atento
Gracias de antemano